# Why two different answers are coming for the same value in case 2: on Java 7?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, type-conversion

Why two different answers are coming for the same value in case 2:  on Java 7?

```
class Ideone
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    System.out.println("Case 1:"); 
    long size=(long)1<<39;
    System.out.println("size :"+size); 
    size=1024*1024*1024*512l;
    System.out.println("size :"+size);  
    System.out.println("Case 2:"); 
    size=(long)1<<41;
    System.out.println("size :"+size); 
    size=1024*1024*1024*1024*2l;
    System.out.println("size :"+size);
  }
}
```

Answers are given below from Ideone.

```
Case 1:
size :549755813888
size :549755813888 
Case 2:
size :2199023255552
size :0
```

Comment: Change to `1024L*1024L*1024L*1024L*2L` and see what happens.

Comment: or `(long)1024*1024*1024*1024*2` and they will be same

Comment: @RealSkeptic Only the first operand needs to be a double literal, right?

Comment: @AndrewLi yes, but if you're working with longs, you better get into the habit of using long literals.

Comment: i agree with your point, but then why case 1 is working? i.e.. size=1024*1024*1024*512l;
System.out.println("size :"+size); . it is giving the result which is more than (2^31) - 1.

Comment: @MohdAltaf Because `1024*1024*1024` still fits inside an `int`, so it won't be 0 after collapsing.

Comment: @JornVernee no, check once again, it is 1024*1024*1024*512  out of range of int.

Comment: @MohdAltaf Yes, but the `512` is a `long` literal. You simply have a large int * 512L, which is then kept as a `long`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing zero is because it's a Integer overflow. In this exact scenario you trigger the [JLS Multiplication Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1) which states that the lower end bits will be the result of a overflow.

For example

```
System.out.println((1025*1024*1024*1024*2));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1025*1024*1024*1024*2));
```

Will print out

```
-2147483648 // Integer overflow
10000000000000000000000000000000 // Integer overflow
```

In your case

```
System.out.println((1024*1024*1024*1024*2)); 
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1024*1024*1024*1024*2));
```

It will print out

```
0 // still a overflow, but the lower ordered bits are 0, since we dont see trailing zero bits
0
```

So what exactly happens is that you calculation starts off with an Integer

```
size=1024*1024*1024*1024*2l;
```

If you don't state that it's a long, it will not handle it as such.
To fix it you have to use uppercase `L` or lowercase `l` at the first operand.

```
 size=1024L*1024*1024*1024*2l;

    System.out.println((1024L*1024*1024*1024*2l));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1024L*1024*1024*1024*2l)); // will not work, because the compiler knows it's a long
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(1024L*1024*1024*1024*2l));
```

The result is

```
2199023255552 // long value
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: i agree that overflow is in case 2 . but that's why i have also mentioned case 1 where overflow is also there but in this case overflow is automatically handled without any casting.

Comment: @MohdAltaf There is no overflow. `1024*1024*1024` is a valid Integer value and you multiply that with `512l` which is a long value. Thus the result is a long value. In the other hand `1024*1024*1024*1024*512l` will overflow with an Integer.

Comment: @MohdAltaf If this answer satisfies you, you might aswell accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**

1024 is an `int`. So 1024 * 1024 * 1024 is performed in `int` arithmetic, that is, in 32 bits. Since 1024 is 2^10, 1024 * 1024 * 1024 is 2^30, so it fits in a 32-bit `int`. Next you multiply by 512L, that is, a `long` (please use capital L; it’s so easy to misread a small l for digit 1). Therefore, 2^30 is converted to `long` and the two `long` values are multiplied. Result is 2^39, which fits in a `long` (would not have fit in an `int`). All is fine.

**Case 2**

1024 * 1024 * 1024 is 2^30 as before, and is an `int` as before. The next 1024 is in `int` too, so the next multiplication is done in 32-bit arithmetic and overflows because the result would have been 2^40, which cannot fit in. Since the number ends in 32 zeros, the result is 0. This is now converted to `long` (0L) so it can be multiplied by 2L. 0 * 2 is 0 (no matter if you do it in 32 or 64 bits).

**Fix**

As has been said, it’s technically enough to mark one of the constants as `long` (with the L), as long as you do it before the overflow happens. `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L * 2` or `1024L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2` should work. I do, however, prefer `1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 2L`. I find it easier to read and understand. Other options I find nice include `1L << 41` and `0x200_0000_0000`.